# Errors in OpenCV Librabry - 2.4.9

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I followed this tutorial to be able to test some samples OpenCV-Android. It is a simple tutorial to make run a first application on your android phone with OpenCV :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2onPuDZQVY

After you clean all the project, it is supposed to be that OpenCV Library - 2.4.9 project appears without any errors.

But I have errors that are displayed when I try to clean all the projects. They occurs about the OpenCV Library - 2.4.9 project.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'OpenCV Library - 2.4.9'.
Resource '/OpenCV Library - 2.4.9/bin' does not exist.
Resource '/OpenCV Library - 2.4.9/bin' does not exist.
```

So I still have all the errors I had in OpenCV Library - 2.4.9 project (when I am supposed to find it without any of them after this step).

Moreover, I looked in the CameraBridgeViewBase.java, for exemple, and an error appear when it is written: R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase_camera_id, -1

I don't see any R.java file in the project, so what is this "R." ?

Comment: R.java is an auto-generated resource file that declares all the resource constants used in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click in your properties project at right side select version in column target name in "Project Build Target" and click apply. Then go to -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor Right side at current builder -> change to Android Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your OpenCV Library - 2.4.9 project, click "Android" tab on the left, you'll see "Project Build Target" on the right, choose the one in it and click ok.